# append response from ipinfo.io to contact form message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a contact form. It works. I'd like to append info to the message/textarea:

`<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>`

To add something to the form message I can do this in a Javascript script:

```
document.form_name.message.value=document.form_name.message.value + (the stuff I want to add);
```

Recently, I discovered the service ipinfo.io that delivers loads of useful information. Although I don't know anything about jquery, I understand how to display this information on a website. See http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/2/

But I just can't make my javascript add/append the reponse information from ipinfo.io to the message of my contact form. Ideally, the message of my contact form would look like this:

[the message people enter in my contact form]
Location: [the city, region, country reported from ipinfo.io]

My trial&error amateur scripting skills are just not enough to solve this.
I hope you can help me. Thank you.

AJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append on submit event of form

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" action="">

    <textarea id="msg" name="msg"> Message </textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $('#form1').submit(function(e){
       $("#msg").val( $("#msg").val() + '\n IP: '+ response.ip  +'\n Location:' + response.city + ", " + response.region);
        alert( $("#msg").val());

        //remove this on live form
        e.preventDefault();
    }) 
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: if it works then accept this as answer.. and for other issues post a new question with sample code that shows the error

Comment: I'm new here. Kind of overlooked the obvious way to say thank you. Sorry.